# 0x80190195 Status 405 when downloading google calender ics using bitsadmin

Tags: batch, download

In a batch script I wrote:

```
Set src="http://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/j<MORE>@gmx.net/private-c<MORE>e/basic.ics"
Set dst="D:\Data\ICS\basic.ics"
bitsadmin  /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal %src% %dst%
pause
```

Instead of `<MORE>` there is actual information that I want to keep to myself.

Here is a screenshot that shows what happens when I call the batch script.

[image]

When I use the same URL in an internet explorer the download starts as expected.
 It does not matter for this error if there is a file D\Data\ICS\basic.ics

What am I doing wrong? Why is this not downloading the file?

Comment: Are there any special characters in the parts you obscured?

Comment: @DavidPostill No, alphanumerical and dashes. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-1234567890

Comment: The response from the server is `405 Method not allowed`. I don't use `bitsadmin` , but it looks like its not performing a normal HTTP GET request.